# When is the inverse of a reciprocated function equal to the function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f(x)=f(-\frac{1}{x})$, are there finite or infinite solutions for this? Can we tell? Thank you very much.

Comment: I would interpret "inverse of a reciprocated function" to mean $g^{-1}$ where $g(x)=1/f(x)$.

Comment: @Rahul I just wanted a name for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any function $g(x)$.  Then, let $f$ be defined as

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(x),&x\ge0\\\\
g(-x^{-1}),&x<0
\end{cases}$$

Then, we have for all $x$ $$f(x)=f(-x^{-1})$$

Answer (score 1):

Try $$f(x)=f\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)=a$$
where $a$ is a constant. There is an infinite amount of solutions for $a$.

Another function that works is
$$f(x)=f\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{1}{x}+x$$

Comment: How would we know?

Comment: @AAron In the former case, $\frac{df}{dx}=0$.